# In Kentico CMS, how do you programmatically Subscribe Users to Newsletters?

Tags: content-management-system, newsletter, subscribe, kentico

Upon completion of a custom payment form I add two user roles, a badge, and two friends.  All of those changes work well and populate to the User object and corresponding database tables.  When I use the below code (copied and altered from Kentico CMS install) I get IsSubscribed == true, but the user never appears to be subscribed.  Any ideas?

```
int newsletterId = 3;
Subscriber sb = SubscriberProvider.GetSubscriber("cms.user", currentUser.UserID);
    if (sb == null)
     {
            // Create new subscriber
            sb = SaveSubscriber(); // CreateSubscriber(value[0], itemId);
      }
      // If subscriber exists and is not subscribed, subscribe him
      if ((sb != null) && (!SubscriberProvider.IsSubscribed(sb.SubscriberID, newsletterId)))
      {
         try
         {
             SubscriberProvider.Subscribe(sb.SubscriberID, newsletterId, DateTime.Now, false);
             lblTroubledUser.Text = "shoulda been subscribed to newsletter";
         }
         catch
         {
              lblTroubledUser.Text = "problem subscribing to newsletter";
         }
      }
      else
            lblTroubledUser.Text = (!SubscriberProvider.IsSubscribed(sb.SubscriberID, newsletterId)) ? "sb is null" : "already subscribed to newsletter!";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it!  After you build the Subscriber you have to add them to the Newsletter.  You have to use:

```
SubscriberNewsletterInfoProvider.AddSubscriberToNewsletter(sb.SubscriberID, newsletterId, DateTime.Now);
```